# Validation event for custom widget

Tags: flutter

In flutter, a TextFormField for an example, has a validator which can be used for validation:

```
 TextFormField(validator: validator ...
```

Then in your form, you can call validate on the Form widget to make all children with these validators validate:

```
_formKey.currentState!.validate()
```

If a validation fails, the TextFormField will display an error text along with a position and color transition.

I have my own custom photo widget, and I would like to make it able to support the same validation functionality. That is, give it a validator, hook it up to the `validate()` event, and if the user hasn´t added any photo, the validation fails and shows the error text the validator returns.
But I cannot figure out how to implement the validate eventlistener on a custom widget. So how would you go around this?

### Update:

@user18309290 pointed me in the direction of extending my widget from FormField. But the problem is that my widget has internal functions and properties I need to access in the instance/layout tree. But I can´t figure out the right way to do it. I could put all the stuff in the build method, but that means that all of my "heavy" logic and properties would be reinstantiated every time the widget rebuilds if I understand correctly. So how do I extend from FormField to have validation support (validation fails if image list is empty), but still have access to my methods and properties?

This is my simplified widget:

```
class MyPhotoComponent extends FormField<List<File>> {
  late String title;
  List<File> images = [];

  openCamera() {
    print('This and other methods, has alot of logic');
    images.add(File('filepath'));
  }

  String internalTitle = 'Internal title';

  MyPhotoComponent({required String title, required FormFieldSetter<List<File>> onSaved, FormFieldValidator<List<File>>? validator, required List<File> initialValue, Key? key})
      : super(
          onSaved: onSaved,
          validator: validator,
          initialValue: initialValue,
          key: key,
          builder: (FormFieldState<List<File>> state) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(internalTitle), //Error: The instance member 'internalTitle' can't be accessed in an initializer.
                      MyOtherPhotoGalleryComponent(images: images), //Error: The instance member 'images' can't be accessed in an initializer.
                      ElevatedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: openCamera, //Error: The instance member 'openCamera' can't be accessed in an initializer.
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                        label: Text('Take photo'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
                if (state.hasError) Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => Text('Validation error'))
              ],
            );
          },
        );
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will represent the error

Comment: There is no error. I would just like to know how to subscribe to the validate() event in a child widget.

Answer (score 4):

Inherit a custom widget from [FormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html). Each individual form field should be wrapped in a [FormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html) widget like [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html).

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        validator: (String? value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      CustomFormField(
        validator: (String? value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please select something';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
        },
        child: const Text('Submit'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I done some research based on your suggestion of extending from FormField. That seems to be the right way to go, but it does not quite solve the problem. I have updated my question and described the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to accomplish this

1. State management which will be complicated for this scenario
2. SetState() which will update your whole UI and will be expensive
3. ValueNotifier and ValueListableBuilder which I recommend

First define a valuenotifier

```
late ValueNotifier<bool> _isValid;
```

Then in initState initialize it and add a listener to it which will be your validator

```
...
_isValid = ValueNotifier(true);
_isValid.addListener((){
    If(){ //your validation
        _isValid.value = true;
    } else {
        _isValid.value = false;
    }
})
```

Then in your UI add ValueListableBuilder and put your widget inside it to listen to its changes and change accordingly

```
ValueListableBuilder(
    listenableValue: _isValid,
    builder: (context, bool yourValue, child){
        // return your widget and use yourValue to update your UI
 }
)
```

Sorry if there is any misspelling. I wrote it on my mobile

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use the existing flutter way of validating. I have updated my questen.

Answer (score 0):

you can extends FormField<T> (if you check value is String => `FormField<String>`)

- InfoCategoryForm

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'info_category.dart';

class InfoCategoryForm extends FormField<String> {
  InfoCategoryForm({
    super.key,
    String? selectType,
    required Widget page,
    super.validator,
    super.restorationId,
    super.onSaved,
  }) : super(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
          enabled: true,
          initialValue: selectType,        // <---- update validat value
          builder: (FormFieldState<String> field) {
            return UnmanagedRestorationScope(
              child: InfoCategoryWidget(
                selectType: selectType,
                page: page,
                errorText: field.errorText,  // <--- get error message
              ),
            );
          },
        );

  @override
  FormFieldState<String> createState() => _InfoCategoryFormState();
}

class _InfoCategoryFormState extends FormFieldState<String> {}
```

the point is `errorText`, `InfoCategoryWidget` is my custom button widget

- InfoCategoryWidget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfoCategoryWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const InfoCategoryWidget({
    super.key,
    this.selectType,
    required this.page,
    this.errorText,
  });

  final String? selectType;
  final Widget page;
  final String? errorText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,

        ...

            BottomSheetButton(
              page: page,
              child: Text(
                selectType ?? S.of(context).categoryWarnMsg,
                style: selectType == null
                    ? CustomTextStyle.subTitleHint
                    : CustomTextStyle.subTitle,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (errorText != null)
          Text(
            errorText!,                        // <--- custom your error message
            style: CustomTextStyle.error,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

- use

```dart
InfoCategoryForm(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  selectType: CategoryEnum.getName(state.tag)?.name,
  page: InfoSelectTypePage(
    onPressed: (type) => context
        .read<SavingsBloc>()
        .add(AddTypeEvent(tag: type.index)),
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return 'test aaa';
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```